# Can't pass form data to PHP to update Database

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

Thanks to all who responded. I got it to update with a combination of ideas from you. I've amended the code to show what's working.

To implement LIKE functionality by passing the LIKE button value to php so as to update the DB.

This displays the table, complete with a LIKE button per row:

```
echo '<table>
           <tr>
            <th>Word ID</th>
            <th>User ID</th>
            <th>User Name</th>
            <th>Word</th>
            <th>Meaning</th>
            <th>Example</th>
           </tr>';

    foreach ($data as $row) 
      { 
        echo '<tr>';
            foreach ($row as $value)
                  { 
                echo '<td>';
                    echo $value;
                echo '</td>';
              } 


    echo '<td>
 <form method="POST" action="'.$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"].'">
<input type="hidden" name="LIKE" value="'.$row['wordID'].'">
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Submit">
</form>

                 </td>';

            echo '</tr>';
          }
        echo '</table>';
```

The code to process the form submit is:

```
    if($_POST['submit']) 
 {
$sql = "UPDATE vocab SET likes = likes+1 where wordID = '{$row['wordID']}'"; 

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

/* Execute */
            $stmt->execute();

}
```

Comment: Should `'{$row['wordID']}'` be `'{$_POST['wordID']}'` in your update?  (also please use place holders rather than inserting the value into the SQL)

Comment: Also change `action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]?>` to `action="'. $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"].'` .  Your mixing your code up to much.

Comment: Afraid that made no difference.

Comment: I agree, Nigel! I'm mixing my code up  - I find it very hard to embed php in html. Still can't get it working :(

Comment: Try and split this down, echo each part separately (different echo) .  Makes it easier to read (IMHO)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]?>
```

is a sytax you use when you are NOT already in a `<?php` tag. Here, you already are writing in PHP and in an `echo` and you just apen again a `<?php`, and another `echo` in it, this makes no sense.

```
echo '...  <form method="post" action="'.$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"].'">  ...';
```

is the way you want to include your php_self value.

**also**

```
<input type="submit" value="LIKE" name="<?php echo $row["wordID"]; ?></form>
```

should be

```
<input type="submit" value="LIKE" name="'.$row['wordID'].'"></form>
```

but you cant the search for $_POST['wordID'], search for $_POST[$row['wordID']] in a for loop.

Comment: Thanks. I've got that now. I get no errors now, but the DB doesn't update.

Comment: have you done the same with php echo $row["wordID"] ? take a look at my edit

Comment: @Hego it's your `if($_POST['wordID'])` that's wrong then, just put `if($_POST[$row['wordID']])` in a for loop like you did for the html

Comment: thanks for your help. I have it updating the database but not correctly. At least everything is now talking to everything and I have to look at my program logic to get it to update correctly. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing an `echo` inside an `echo` here :

```
echo '<td>
            <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]?>
            <input type="submit" value="LIKE" name="<?php echo $row["wordID"]; ?></form>
                 </td>';
```

`<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]?>`

should be :

`<form method="post" action="'.$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"].'">`

Comment: As this is in single quotes, it won't do any substitutions.

Comment: OK, thanks. I've followed your syntax, and also for the name attribute:

echo '<td>
 <form method="post" action="'.$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"].'">
 <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="LIKE" name="'.$row["wordID"].'"></form>
     </td>';
I no longer get a 404 but the DB isn't updating.

Answer (score 1):

i would do this:

```
<td>
<form method='POST'>
<input type='hidden' name='LIKE' value='".$row['wordId']."'>
<input type='submit' value='Submit'>
</form>
</td>
```

Action will always default to : PHP_SELF so no point adding that, additionally adding the hidden field instead of the submit button is preferable to me as it's easier to read, plus adds an easy option incase you actually want to add more to the form (which is entirely possible)

Comment: I tried that but got a syntax error, unexpected 'POST' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'

I'm changing ' to " in your code snippet but still not getting it to work.

Comment: $sql = "UPDATE vocab SET likes = likes+1 where wordID = '{$row['wordID']}'"; <--- this should be $_POST['LIKE'] using my example above.

Comment: Sorry, could you just clarify. What do I replace with $_POST['LIKE'] ?

Comment: thanks for your help. I have it updating the database so the syntax issue is now resolved. Updating is INCORRECT so I have to look at my program logic to get it to update correctly. If I can't sort it out I'll post a new question.